# getIntent не работает

Tags: java, android

Фрагмент

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CatalogItem.class)
    .putExtra("oId",jsonArrayResponse.getJSONObject(position).getString("oId")));
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Активити

```
oId = getIntent().getIntExtra("oId");
Log.e("AAAAA=onCreate", String.valueOf(oId));
```

---

В Фрагменте

```
E/AAAAA=onCreate: 1280
```

В Активити

```
E/AAAAA=doInBackground: 8
```

Почему не передается значение? и откуда берется число 8. Когда должно быть 1280?

Comment: Пробовали туда передавать какое то число, не из json, для теста?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, да передается.

Comment: Вы уверены что значение которое вы достаете из JSON правильное? и зачем вам String.valueOf если oId и так строка?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, В JSon строка. Я передаю ее в активити, Из активити я должен получить Int. Но получаю 8. Вместо 1280

Comment: Я все равно не пойму, почему вы ложите в интент строку , а достаете из него int.   Попробуйте getStringExtra() вместо getIntExtra()

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Ну я как понимаю если положить строку и вынести int. То она автоматически переконвертиться в int. Разве не так?

Comment: Я не в курсе, но вообще лучше брать из интента то, что вы туда ложили. И попробуйте занести значение в переменную из jsonArrayResponse.getJSONObject(position).getString("oId")) потом вывести ее в логи, и потом уже эту переменную положить в интенты